# Managing multiple UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have defined IBOutletCollection of UIActivityIndicatorView.

```
IBOutletCollection(UIActivityIndicatorView) NSArray *ticker;
```

After making the required connections in the Interface builder, I run the following code.

```
for (UIActivityIndicatorView *obj in ticker)
 {
            [obj startAnimating];
 }
```

But I get this message on the console:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIActivityIndicatorView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2c86a0'

I know it might be a very small problem with it, but really not getting it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what it's not working for you. I have done the following and it works fine.

in my .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutletCollection(UIActivityIndicatorView) NSArray *activityIndicators;
```

in my .m (if not using Xcode 4.4)

```
@synthesize activityIndicators
```

I added 7+ activity indicators to my StoryBoard and connected them to my viewController

in my viewDidLoad i'm calling

```
for (UIActivityIndicatorView *obj in self.activityIndicators){
        [obj startAnimating];
    }
```

Works fine for me in this configuration no problems.

Based on the error message you're getting

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIActivityIndicatorView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]
```

Sounds like something not set right, check your IB that you haven't done something odd.

Comment: Thanks. There was something wrong with the IB. I couldn't figure what was it, but just removed all the connections and made them again. It worked then.

Answer (score 0):

The method `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` is supposed to be sent to the array object as part of the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol. Sometimes messages can get sent to the wrong object if there's a memory issue. Double-check to make sure that `ticker` is being properly retained (and it might also be best practice to use `self.ticker`).